# Get git patch of current modified files

Tags: git, patch

As a noob in git, i have no idea how to have patch to current modified files relative to original ones, i.e. the first git clone.
Anyone experienced expert on this developmental software versioning, mainly `patch` and diff for working as collaborator (in fork, PR, etc) so that explain the correct way ?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: A patch describes the diff between state A and state B. Can you be more specific about A and B in your case? Do you mean a patch for the diff between the initial commit and `HEAD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Making a patch

You can create a patch that represents all your uncommitted changes simply by saving the output of `git diff` to a file:

```sh
git diff > my-changes.patch
```

This patch is just a file, and so you could email it to someone or save it on a thumb drive or do whatever else you wanted to with it (I'm not sure why you'd need to do this, but you can)

Then, the patch can be applied via

```sh
git apply my-changes.patch
```

**You typically don't need to make patches manually, and when you do need to make patches, they should always be from pre-existing commits.**

A patch can be made from pre-existing commits like so:

```
git diff <start commit>..HEAD > my-changes.patch
```

This will create a patch of all changes since `<start commit>`. You can also specify `<start commit>` as a branch, a tag (which refers to a specific commit), or something specific like `main~10` (which would mean the main branch, 10 commits ago).

```sh
# Get a patch of all changes that haven't been pushed
git diff origin/main..main > local-changes.patch

# Get a patch of all changes on feature-branch
git diff main..feature-branch > changes-on-feature-branch.patch

# Get the last 10 commits as a patch
git diff main~10..main > last-10-commits.patch

# Get all the changes since a particular tag
git diff v1.0.0..main > changes-since-v1.0.0.patch
```

**ONCE AGAIN, YOU TYPICALLY DO NOT NEED TO CREATE PATCHES MANUALLY!!!** As a tool, `git diff` is really useful for exploring history, seeing current changes, seeing changes that will get merged, or a million other uses. It outputs stuff in a form that can be directly applied with `git apply`, but I haven't had to manually send someone a patch at any point in my entire life.

## Collaborating in git, the right way

There are three typical ways to collaborate, which I'll list from easiest to most advanced.

### Method 1: Multiple collaborators, who all have access

This is the most typical situation you'll see in school, or in most work environments. Everyone can push code to the same repository.

Once you have a copy of the repo on your machine, the workflow looks like this:

- Make changes or updates to the code
- Commit your changes: `git add <your changes> && git commit`

  You can make as many commits as you want before uploading. The best thing to do is make small commits every time you finish an important piece of code, like a function, or a class.
- Download remote changes: `git pull`

  If your partners or coworkers have updated the repository with changes, you have to do this before pushing. This allows you to check to make sure that your changes work with their changes.
- Upload your changes: `git push`

### Method 2: you're working on someone else's open source project

You won't always be able to push your changes directly. For example, if you're working on an open source project, you'll typically submit changes for review, and the maintainers will be the ones to merge them.

This is typically done by forking the project, making changes, uploading your changes to your repository (the forked version), and then submitting a pull request to integrate your changes back into the original project.

It looks like this:

- Fork (on github, gitlab, or another service
- Clone the forked version onto your local machine
- Make changes
- Commit your changes
- Push your changes
- Create a pull request to merge your changes back in (You can do this on github, gitlab, or wherever you forked the repo)

### Method 3: Email your commits as a patch

This method is typically used for larger, older open-source projects, that don't want to rely on a centralized service like github or gitlab.

It's done by using [`git send-email`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email) to email the patches directly from the command line. Git will create a patch for you automatically. All you have to do is specify the range of commits you want to send as a patch.

For example, if you made your changes on a local branch called `dev`, then you would use it like this:

```sh
git send-email --compose --from=<your email> --to=<their email> master..dev
```

Here, `master..dev` is the range of patches you're sending. It's all the patches on the `dev` branch, that aren't on the master branch. AKA, your changes.

This command will open a text editor where you can write the body of your email, and git will attach the patch to the email, and send it.

Note that you have to configure your email to work with git send-email. Beginners will not typically need to do this.

Comment: "collaborators who all have access"
how can anyone can do such easily modify other's belonging or property? Please help explain clearly

Comment: Typically speaking everyone would have access if it were a team effort, like for a company, or school assignment. Many hosting providers also have ways to set up different tiers of access. For example, most people may not have permission to force push, or may only be allowed to push to particular branches.